# Library missing after port update on FreeBSD

Tags: package-management, freebsd, samba, shared-library

I have been confronted with some strange behavior after upgrading my ports with

```
portupgrade --all --interactive
```

I always miss "**libsamba-credentials.so.0**" (from "/usr/local/lib", symlink to "libsamba-credentials.so.0.0.1") after upgrading. The behavior can be reproduced. The following is noticeable when upgrading a port, which I didn't notice before:

```
pkg: unknown format pkg, using the default
```

Here is the relevant part of the upgrade process:

```
====> Compressing man pages (compress-man)
===> Staging rc.d startup script(s)
--->  Build of sysutils/graylog ended at: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 23:08:57 +0200 (consumed 00:00:37)
--->  Updating dependency info
--->  Uninstallation of graylog-4.1.2 started at: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 23:08:58 +0200
--->  Fixing up dependencies before creating a package
--->  Backing up the old version
pkg: unknown format pkg, using the default
--->  Uninstalling the old version
[Reading data from pkg(8) ... - 1371 packages found - done]
--->  Deinstalling 'graylog-4.1.2'
Updating database digests format: 100%
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Deinstallation has been requested for the following 1 packages (of 0 packages in the universe):

Installed packages to be REMOVED:
        graylog: 4.1.2

Number of packages to be removed: 1

The operation will free 239 MiB.
[1/1] Deinstalling graylog-4.1.2...
[1/1] Deleting files for graylog-4.1.2: 100%
==> You should manually remove the "graylog" user.
==> You should manually remove the "graylog" group
You may need to manually remove /usr/local/etc/graylog/graylog.conf if it is no longer needed.
[Reading data from pkg(8) ... - 1370 packages found - done]
--->  Uninstallation of graylog-4.1.2 ended at: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 23:10:47 +0200 (consumed 00:01:49)
--->  Installation of sysutils/graylog started at: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 23:10:47 +0200
--->  Installing the new version via the port
===>  Deinstalling for graylog
===>   graylog not installed, skipping
===>  Installing for graylog-4.1.3
===>  Checking if graylog is already installed
===>   Registering installation for graylog-4.1.3
Installing graylog-4.1.3...
===> Creating groups.
Using existing group 'graylog'.
===> Creating users
Using existing user 'graylog'.
Please see /usr/local/etc/graylog for sample versions of graylog.conf, log4j.xml, and
and adjust them for your configuration.

For GeoIP support you need to install the net/GeoIP port and
configure the path to the GeoIP databases in the Graylog Web Interface.

When running graylog in a jail, you need to set enforce_statfs for the jail.

For a single-node installation, install:

- databases/mongodb40 or higher
- textproc/elasticsearch6 or higher

And ensure that the elasticsearch cluster name matches that used by graylog.


===>  Cleaning for graylog-4.1.3
--->  Removing temporary files and directories
--->  Removing old package'
--->  Installation of sysutils/graylog ended at: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 23:10:57 +0200 (consumed 00:00:09)
--->  Cleaning out obsolete shared libraries
No such file or directory @ rb_check_realpath_internal - /usr/local/lib/compat/pkg/libsamba-credentials.so.0
--->  Upgrade of sysutils/graylog ended at: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 23:11:03 +0200 (consumed 00:03:24)
--->  ** Upgrade tasks 4: 1 done, 2 ignored, 0 skipped and 0 failed
```

Can someone please push me in the right direction?

PS: Samba 4.13.4 was installed from source from samba.org.

--- UPDATE 2021-08-19 ---

Turns out, `portsclean -L` removes the link /usr/local/lib/libsamba-credentials.so.0. But why?

Comment: I'd start with upgrading `pkg` to 1.17 first.

Comment: The attempt to upgrading `pkg` results in `The most recent versions of packages are already installed`

Comment: And what version is it?

Comment: Version of pkg is 1.17.1 - Remember, the issue is a removed file by portsclean.